# How to re-activate disabled Apache 2.2 AJP connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I don't use AJP for load-balancing; I have a *single* Apache 2.2 instance that proxies some URLs to a *single* Tomcat 7 instance via AJP.

When Tomcat is down, the AJP proxy becomes disabled on the first failed request, and is *not* re-enabled when Tomcat is brought back up.

Is it possible to instruct Apache to *not disable* AJP connection, even though the backend is down, so that the proxy starts working the moment the backend is back online?

Here's an excerpt from my httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass /my-web-app ajp://localhost:8009/my-we-app-1.0.2
```

And here's the log file when the backend is down:

```
[error] (OS 10061)No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
[error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure; instruct Apache to never wait to retry that backend connection (it's waiting 60 seconds, by default) with `retry=0`:

```
ProxyPass /my-web-app ajp://localhost:8009/my-we-app-1.0.2 retry=0
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I needed, thanks. Never tried waiting >60 seconds, too impatient for that :D